# Function in linq select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression

I have this error :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method: `GetDebitOuCredit`

When I run this:

```cs
using (SXEntities db = new SXEntities())
{
    result = from ecriture in db.Ecrits
             join compte in db.Comptes on ecriture.Compte equals compte.Compte1
             join societe in db.Societes on ecriture.Societe equals societe.Societe1                             
             select new EcritDTO
             {
                 LibelleElement = compte.Libelle,
                 LienGED = string.Empty, // WIP
                 Compte = ecriture.Compte,
                 Collectif = ecriture.RacColtif,
                 Date = ecriture.DateC,
                 Journal = ecriture.Journal,
                 Piece = ecriture.Piece,
                 CodeOperation = ecriture.CodeOpe,
                 Libelle = ecriture.Libelle,
                 ReferenceDocument = ecriture.DocuRef,
                 // Error just below
                 Debit = GetDebitOuCredit("Debit", societe.DCMoins, ecriture.MtDeb, ecriture.MtCre),
             };
}
```

I cannot use this function:

```cs
public double GetDebitOuCredit(string choix, string dcMoins, double? montantDebit, double? montantCredit)
{
    double debit = 0;
    double credit = 0;
    bool isMontantNegatif = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dcMoins) && dcMoins == "1";

    if(montantDebit != null && montantDebit != 0 && montantCredit != null && montantCredit != 0)
    {
        double difference = (double)montantDebit - (double)montantCredit;

        if(difference < 0 && isMontantNegatif)
        {
            debit = 0;
            credit = Math.Abs(difference);
        }
        else
        {
            debit = difference;
            credit = 0;
        }
    }

    return choix == "Debit" ? debit : credit;
}
```

My question: How can I transform my function `GetDebitOrCredit` to LINQ expression?

Comment: How many rows are being returned?

Comment: EF LINQ queries are translated to SQL. How can a local function get translated to SQL?

Comment: In any case, that function doesn't need to be a LINQ expression. It could easily be a calculated property of `EcritDTO` or applied to the objects *after* loading them.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if it is final projection, you don't have to translate this function.
If not, you have to use third party extensions for that:

https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler

https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq/

Never tried `DelegateDecompiler`, so will show sample using `NeinLinq`

```cs
[InjectLambda]
public double GetDebitOuCredit(string choix, string dcMoins, double? montantDebit, double? montantCredit)
{
   _getDebitOuCreditFunc ??= GetDebitOuCredit().Compile();
   return _getDebitOuCreditFunc(choix, dcMoins, montantDebit, montantCredit);
}

static Func<string, string, double?, double?, double> _getDebitOuCreditFunc;

public static Expression<Func<string, string, double?, double?, double>> GetDebitOuCredit()
{
    return (choix, dcMoins, montantDebit, montantCredit) =>
       montantDebit != null && montantDebit != 0 && montantCredit != null && montantCredit != 0) 
       ? ((double)montantDebit < (double)montantCredit) && dcMoins == "1" 
          ? choix == "Debit" ? 0 : (double)montantCredit) - (double)montantDebit
          : choix == "Debit" ? (double)montantDebit - (double)montantCredit) : 0
        : 0;
}
```

Then you can use your function in LINQ queries after `ToInjectable()` call.

```cs
result = from ecriture in db.Ecrits.ToInjectable()
         join compte in db.Comptes on ecriture.Compte equals compte.Compte1
         ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot to actually run the query and it's running later when you try to apply some other operation to it.  Try

```
using (SXEntities db = new SXEntities())
{
    var q  = from ecriture in db.Ecrits
             join compte in db.Comptes on ecriture.Compte equals compte.Compte1
             join societe in db.Societes on ecriture.Societe equals societe.Societe1                             
             select new EcritDTO
             {
                 LibelleElement = compte.Libelle,
                 LienGED = string.Empty, // WIP
                 Compte = ecriture.Compte,
                 Collectif = ecriture.RacColtif,
                 Date = ecriture.DateC,
                 Journal = ecriture.Journal,
                 Piece = ecriture.Piece,
                 CodeOperation = ecriture.CodeOpe,
                 Libelle = ecriture.Libelle,
                 ReferenceDocument = ecriture.DocuRef,
                 // Error just below
                 Debit = GetDebitOuCredit("Debit", societe.DCMoins, ecriture.MtDeb, ecriture.MtCre),
             };
     result = q.ToList();
}
```

Also you should be able to remove the joins and do something like:

```
using (SXEntities db = new SXEntities())
{
    var q  = from ecriture in db.Ecrits      
             select new EcritDTO
             {
                 LibelleElement = ecriture.Compte.Libelle,
                 LienGED = string.Empty, // WIP
                 Compte = ecriture.Compte,
                 Collectif = ecriture.RacColtif,
                 Date = ecriture.DateC,
                 Journal = ecriture.Journal,
                 Piece = ecriture.Piece,
                 CodeOperation = ecriture.CodeOpe,
                 Libelle = ecriture.Libelle,
                 ReferenceDocument = ecriture.DocuRef,
                 // Error just below
                 Debit = GetDebitOuCredit("Debit", ecriture.Societe.DCMoins, ecriture.MtDeb, ecriture.MtCre),
             };
     result = q.ToList();
}
```

Assuming your model has proper navigation properties.

Comment: I put the ToList() but impossible to execute GetDebitOuCredit() : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method..

Comment: what version of EF?

Comment: this is the version 6